# Safari Autofill is using the wrong Contacts card

Tags: safari

I am using Safari 7. The Autofill feature is using the wrong card in my Contacts list. How can I get Safari to use my Contacts card?

Answer (score 2):

Check that the correct card is selected as your "Me" card in Contacts. Open Contacts and select "Go to My Card" from the Card menu. If the wrong one is selected, find the correct one, select it and mark it with "Mark This My Card" from the card menu.

Within Safari Preferences you could also check the AutoFill tab. Make sure "Using info from my Contacts card" is ticked.